# HTML Autocomplete - Blank space adds at bottom everytime on mouseover

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am using `HTML autocomplete` control. I notice a strange thing when my application is running on IE. Each time I mouseover on autocomplete, blank space is added below it. Below is the reference image.

[image]

Following is the code for autocomplete :

```
<span class="searchFormControl">
<%= Html.AutoCompleteFor(model => model.ContactEmail, controller: "ContactEmailAutocomplete", parentId: "ContactId", htmlAttributes: new { @onkeypress = "return allowAlphaNumericAndApostrophe(event);", @onpaste = "return false" })%>
</span>
```

This issue is not coming on Google Chrome.

Comment: There's no such control in the standard ASP.NET MVC library. Please post a link to the website of the control you are using.

Comment: Side note: I'm not sure if there is `AutoCompleteFor` helper as part of ASP.Net-MVC... Maybe good idea to point what control you are using.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Thanks. I will. Have you ever experienced this issue in IE for dropdown?

Comment: No, I've never experienced such an issue for standard dropdowns. But since you are not using a standard dropdown, I guess the problem comes from the control you are using or the way you are using it. Unfortunately I don't know which control you are using (as I said, there's no such helper `AutoCompleteFor` in the standard ASP.NET MVC library)